# Functional equation $f\big(x+f(y)\big) = f(x)-y$ where $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

I'm trying to solve the functional equation $f\big(x+f(y)\big) = f(x)-y$ where $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$. What I got so far is: $f$ is injective and $f(0) = 0$.
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you have observed, $f$ must be injective and satisfy $f(0)=0$.  Now for any fixed $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, setting $y=a$ and $x=0$ gives $f(f(a))=-a$, and then setting $x=f(a)$ gives $f(2f(a))=-2a$.  You can continue similarly to find $f(nf(a))=-na$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  You can also get $f(nf(a))=-na$ for negative integers $n$ by applying this argument backwards (for instance, for $n=-1$ set $x=-f(a)$).

Thus $f(nf(a))=-na$ for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  In particular, if $n=f(b)$ for some $b\in\mathbb{Z}$, this says $$f(f(a)f(b))=-f(b)a=-f(a)b,$$ since you can swap the roles of $a$ and $b$.  Thus assuming $a,b\neq 0$, we find $f(a)/a=f(b)/b$.  Since $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary, this means there is a constant $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ (the common value of $f(a)/a$) such that $f(x)=cx$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Plugging $f(x)=cx$ back into the functional equation gives $$c(x+cy)=cx-y,$$
so $c^2=-1$.  Since no integer can satisfy this, there are no functions which satisfy the functional equation.

Comment: Thanks you very much, got it :)

Comment: Just one thing: I don't follow you when you say, setting $x = f(a)$ gives $f(2(f(a)) = -2a$. Can you give me any hint please? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I got it. We have to set $y=a$ and $x = f(a)$ so we have $f(f(a) + f(y)) = f(x) - y \iff f(2f(a)) = -2a$  thanks :)  :)

Comment: @EricWofsey  Please explain why $f(0)=0$?

Comment: First, if $f(y)=f(z)$, then for any $x$, $f(x+f(y))=f(x+f(z))$ so $f(x)-y=f(x)-z$ so $y=z$.  That is, $f$ is injective.  Now taking $x=y=0$, we get $f(f(0))=f(0)$ and therefore $f(0)=0$.

Comment: We can also get $f(x)=cx$ by plugging first $x=-f(y)$ to get $f(-f(y))=y$ and then plugging $y=-f(y)$ to obtain Cauchy's functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, for which the result is known.

Comment: But if $f(0)=0$ then $f(f(y))=-y$. Meaning that $-f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$. Therefore this can only be a linear function with no independent term and a coefficient of -1. Is that a reasonable answer

Comment: @NeoPlato: Your third sentence is totally unjustified.

Comment: What I thought was there's no other function that can be that close to it's inverse. Unless of course the equation$f(f(x))=x$ has other solutions apart from $f(x)=x$. Just a thought.